# how to print 2d data into 3d, data read from file with python

Tags: python

I would like to print my 2d data into 3d with python as the photo in image bellow. Currently I am reading my data from files where I have the x and y numbers on 2 columns. Any help will be apreciated. The code that prints my data in 2d looks like this:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pylab as pl
 import matplotlib as mpl

 data1 = np.loadtxt('NL_extb_1.xye')
 data2 = np.loadtxt('NL_extb_2.xye')
 data3 = np.loadtxt('NL_extb_3.xye')
 data4 = np.loadtxt('NL_extb_4.xye')
 data5 = np.loadtxt('NL_extb_5.xye')       

 pl.plot(data1[:,0], data1[:,1] , 'black') 
 pl.plot(data2[:,0], data2[:,1], 'black')  
 pl.plot(data3[:,0], data3[:,1] ,'black')
 pl.plot(data4[:,0], data4[:,1] ,'black')
 pl.plot(data5[:,0], data5[:,1] ,'black')


 pl.xlabel("2Theta")
 pl.ylabel("Counts")

 pl.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plot in your image looks like made in `mplot3d`. There is an example how to do it in the [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)   #<-- REPLACE THIS LINE WITH YOUR DATA

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
plt.show()
```

Setting `rstride` or `cstride` to 0 will get you the plot typy you want.

So now, the only thing you should do is to create the correct input variables `X, Y, Z`. I assume that all your `datai` have the same length, say N, and all `x` columns `datai[:0]` **are identical**. (If not, then more work is needed.)
Then

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(1,6), data1[:,0])     
# or maybe the other way:
# X, Y = np.meshgrid(data1[:,0], range(1,6))
```

and `Z` consists of all `y` columns from your data concatenated into an array of the same shape as `X and Y` (all of them should be N x 5 arrays or 5 x N arrays).